# How the Gain/Loss of Arena Rating is calculated

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft, when you do PvP Arena, you gain or lose Arena Rating when you win or lose.

I want to know, is the amount of Rating that you gain or lose a consistent amount or is it calculated based on a few variables (example your current rating, or you win/loss ratio)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arena ratings are calculated using the [ELO rating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELO_rating_system) with a K-factor of 32. This means that maximum that your rating can change by is 32. The rating changes are based primarily off the following formula with some additional adjustments for team size and low ratings:

[image: formula]

<sup>Image from [WOW Wiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/Arena_PvP_system)</sup>

As you can see from above, if a team has a rating lower than 1500 they gain points as if their rating was 1500.

Additionally, there are adjustments based on team size:

- 2v2 teams earn 76% of the points of a 5v5 team with the same rating
- 3v3 teams earn 88% of the points of a 5v5 team with the same rating

Comment: This answer totally confuses conquest points gained per week with arena rating gained with win/loss. How is it accepted?

Comment: If you have a better answer why don't you answer rather than complain without providing any further information?

Comment: Sorry, but I was actually looking for the answer and yours is only confusing and provides no information related to the question. The fact that it is accepted makes it much less probable to get the real answer. That's not a contest for rating, that's place where people look for correct answers. Shame.

Comment: The question is "I want to know, is the amount of Rating that you gain or lose a consistent amount or is it calculated based on a few variables (example your current rating, or you win/loss ratio)?", the answer clearly answers that...